# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. Handling 404 error exception in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

It's a simple MVC template project. And modified project files:
**Program:**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

**Privacy** and **Error** action methods in HomeController.cs

```
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception message");
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
            var contextFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();

            return View(new ErrorViewModel { Message = contextFeature!.Error.Message });
        }
```

**Output:**
[Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nm00q.jpg) **Why is a developer exception page being added below?**(I don't use UseDeveloperExceptionPage())
It happens when HttpContext.Response.StatusCode is being assigned to Status404NotFound, but with others status codes it doesn't. The app runs in Developer mode and IIS Express.

[Expected error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vhnD.jpg)

Comment: To disable developer exception page you can go to your Properties/launchSettings.json file can you change the section "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development" to something else other than "Development" , for instance your project name .

Comment: I tried. Error action method is invoked but nothing is rendered. Empty page

Comment: Tested in IIS or Kestrel. It works fine. So I think maybe it's better ignore this issue as it only happen when developing. Also as the error description, "HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;" shouldn't be used here.

Comment: @Jerry I noticed that in Kestel it works fine, but in IIS doesn't. Maybe it depends on IIS settings?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error page Why is a developer exception page being added below?(I
> don't use UseDeveloperExceptionPage())

Actually, based on your shared code snippet you are getting expected output because while you would use [throw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/throw) which will create an exception manually during the execution of the program and this doing exactly it is. Thus, your next statement will not be executed as throw will be considered as end of the statement.

I have successfully reproduce your isssue:

[image]

[image]

> The app runs in Developer mode and IIS Express.

This by design, The developer exception page runs early in the middleware pipeline, so that it can catch unhandled exceptions thrown in middleware that follows.

Another important point this that, If you are publishing it to IIS make sure to edit this page to display errors properly only in the development or staging environment. NOT in a Production environment, therefore, public-facing clients will not see your site errors, which might show sensitive information as well. You can [check more details here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

**Way To Handle Your Requirement:**

If you have look on your error action method you would get to know the implementation. You would require to do the same way which is you would have a exception message either in a variable on a class then you need to pass that within your view that will produce the exact output you are expecting.

Let's check that in action:

Custom Model:

```
public class InherittedErrorModel: ErrorViewModel
    {
        public string? ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    }
```

**Note:** I am using a new custom model and inheriting base ErrorViewModel so that I can use that property if required.

Controller Action:

```
public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            var exceptionMessage = new Exception("Exception Massage");
            return View(new InherittedErrorModel { ErrorMessage = exceptionMessage.Message});
        }
```

**Note:** Rather throwing the exception (which is breaking your program and causing your issue) I am extracting the error message and passing into view.

View:

```
@model InherittedErrorModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Privacy Policy";
}
<h1 class="text-danger">Error.</h1>
<h3 class="text-danger">@Model.ErrorMessage</h3>
```

Execute Privacy Exception:

If you would like to execute your error handeler which you have define within Privacy you need to change UseExceptionHandler path to Privacy as well.

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Privacy");
```

Note: Its up to your requirement.

Output:

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on it you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0#developer-exception-page-1)